# How to expose 80 and 443 to the Internet with Kubernetes like I did with docker-compose?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

For what I understand, exposing pods or deployments can be achieved with a `NodePort` or a `ClusterIP` or a  `LoadBalancer` service.

Coming from the docker-compose world, my stack was quite easy, I have all my applications running on a private Docker network and a reverse proxy (Caddy or NGINX) running as well but with the only port mapping allowed in my stack : `:80` and `:443` (and it can allow reach the private network of course).

So basically : `Internet ----> Caddy ----> Private applications` in a docker-compose stack.

Q1 : How can I do such things with Kubernetes in a "bare-metal" context ? I mean, if I do not want to use a cloud load balancer provider ?

Q2 : Is it because Kubernetes has never been built to expose applications like this ? Is it automatically dependent to a cloud provider ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: You might want to look in to https://metallb.universe.tf/. It's a loadbalancer that works just as the common cloud loadbalancers but on your local cluster. It's fairly easy to setup and works great with any reverse proxy.
Q2: Kubernetes is primarily developed for cloud environments and is definately is easier to run in that context. To run it locally often requires additional tools to replicate the functionallity of its cloud service counterparts.

Comment: Thanks, that makes totally sense, I felt like something is missing between a cluster and "the Internet". This method only applies to LoadBalancer service type right ? It cannot work with NodePort or ClusterIP ?

Comment: Yes it's geared towards LoadBalancer. From my experience however most applications and services are also focused to work with LoadBalancers, whereas NodePort and ClusterIP are often more tricky to get them working.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on how your networking is setup. Kubernetes typically run in its own network, and now you want traffic outside the cluster to access applications within the cluster - typically over a "gateway" / "proxy".

For http and https traffic, it is common that this "gateway" / "proxy" is a *reverse proxy* configured according to the [Ingress resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) in the cluster by an [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/). You need to use an *Ingress Controller* that support your network setup.

Comment: This is what I understood yes, but technically, why is Kube not capable of listenning on ports 80 and 443 directly ? Like I did with docker-compose ? Basically a `netstat` does not show me Kube listenning to these ports

Comment: What do you mean with "Kube" here? Any pod can listen on port 80 and 443 - but the pods typically has a different IP range than the IP network for the nodes. If your nodes are using a public IP and not its own network then it can work to send traffic to pods directly without a gateway or have the proxy as a Pod. It all depends on how you do the network.